# Does this $\int_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{\log x}{e^x})^n dx$ always have a closed form for $n$ being positive integer ? what about its irrationality?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, closed-form, irrational-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

It is known that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\log x}{e^x}\right)^n dx=-\gamma$ for $n=1$ and for $n=2$ we have :$\frac{1}{12}(\pi^2+6(\gamma+\log 2)^2)$ and for $n=3$ we have [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28%28+log+x%2F%28e%5Ex%29%29%5E3%29%2C+x%3D0+to+infty+) form ,

What I have noted is that for $n$ odd the integrand is negative and for $n$ even the integrand is positive , Now my question here is : How I prove that integral always have a closed form for any fixed integer $n$ ? And can we expect a general formula or any reccurence relation for that integrand for aribitrary integer $n$ ? Also what about its irrationality ?

**For attempt:**  I have tried to use this method for $n=1$ in order to generalise it for any fixed $n$ :
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x} x^k \mathrm{d} x = \Gamma(k+1)
\end{equation}
Differentiate with respect to $k$
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x} x^k \mathrm{ln}(x) \mathrm{d} x = \frac{d\Gamma(k+1)}{dt} = \Gamma(k+1) \psi^{(0)}(k+1)
\end{equation}

Taking the limit $k \to 0$ yields
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x} \mathrm{ln}(x) \mathrm{d} x = \Gamma(1) \psi^{(0)}(1) = -\gamma
\end{equation}
Now for $n=2$ I should use the integration by part I can up to the result but by this way it would be two long and complicated , Then I want probably an abreviate path to deduce any general formula for any arbitary $n$ ?

it is clear only it is irrational for $n=1,2$

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\log(x)}{e^x}\right)^n\,dx&=\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}\log^n(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\log^{n-k}(n)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log^n(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\log^{n-k}(n) \left.\left(\frac{d^n \Gamma(x+1)}{dx^n}\right)\right|_{x=0}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Note that $\gamma$ is not known to be irrational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but I'm sure it'll help:

Let $$I(a) = \int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^a\,dx$$
$$\implies \frac{d^nI(a)}{da^n} = \int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^a(\ln x)^n\,dx$$
Put $nx \rightarrow v$ in the first integral to get:
$$I(a) = \frac1{n^{1+a}}\int_0^\infty e^{-v}v^a\,dv$$
$$\implies I(a) = \frac{\Gamma(1+a)}{n^{1+a}}$$
Now $$\implies \frac{d^nI(a)}{da^n}\bigg|_{a=0} = \frac{d^n}{da^n}\left(\frac{\Gamma(1+a)}{n^{1+a}}\right)\bigg|_{a=0}$$
Which evaluates to:
$$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\Gamma^{(n-k)}(1+a)\ln^k(n)\bigg|_{a=0}$$
Where $\Gamma^{(n-k)}(1+a)$ is the $(n-k)$th derivative of the Gamma function.

Comment: Alternatively, $$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\log(x)}{e^x}\right)^n\,dx&=\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}\log^n(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\log^{n-k}(n)\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log^n(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\log^{n-k}(n) \left.\left(\frac{d^n \Gamma(x+1)}{dx^n}\right)\right|_{x=0}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for ur  hint

Comment: @MarkViola , could u add somethings about its irrationalitry ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I have no idea as to the meaning of "its irrationality" in the context of my comment.

Comment: for every integer n we have a value , Does this value irrational ? ..., or you may deduce it from your finalized closed form

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik I doubt you would be able to deduce anything about rationality. Since the answers you've shown contain the Euler Mascheroni constant, for which we have no idea about rationality